# How can I specify the exact folder IN STREAMLIT for the uploaded file to be saved to?

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to create a simple GUI with streamlit and python for my aspect-based sentiment analysis project, the user should be able to upload a .txt file so that I can run the model on that file. I already created the widget for uploading a file. My question is:

The uploaded file should be added to a specific folder, how can I specify an exact location for the uploaded file to be saved?

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('FILE UPLOAD')
```

(This is the code for the upload widget)

Comment: Im going to assume that you are on a windows machine. If so, then file paths are shown using forward slashes. Your hard drive starts with `C:\\`, and then it goes via folders to your file.

```C:\\Users\\yourname\\yourfile\\yourfile2\\yourfile3\\thefileyouwant.png```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `file_uploader` function does not save the file to disk, it writes to a BytesIO buffer.

> The UploadedFile class is a subclass of BytesIO, and therefore it is “file-like”. This means you can pass them anywhere where a file is expected.

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=file_uploader#streamlit.file_uploader

If you want to save the result as a file, use the standard Python file io capabilities:

```
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(buf.getbuffer())
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to what @RandyZwitch said you can use this function to save to a directory of your choice (directory/folder "tempDir")

```
def save_uploaded_file(uploadedfile):
  with open(os.path.join("tempDir",uploadedfile.name),"wb") as f:
     f.write(uploadedfile.getbuffer())
  return st.success("Saved file :{} in tempDir".format(uploadedfile.name))
```

And apply the function below your uploaded file like below

```
datafile = st.file_uploader("Upload CSV",type=['csv'])
if datafile is not None:
    file_details = {"FileName":datafile.name,"FileType":datafile.type}
    df  = pd.read_csv(datafile)
    st.dataframe(df)
    # Apply Function here
    save_uploaded_file(datafile)
```

Comment: This seems great. Is this supposed to work with Streamlit Sharing? I want to create some sort of temp directory on a live web app. Any insight on that? Thanks

Comment: @JCharis: How would you upload a JSONL file using streamlit, and save it to some session state variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can define path like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = "C:/Projects/ex1/your_file"
file_path = Path(path)

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader(file_path)
```

Comment: I get an error that says:  PosixPath has type PosixPath, but expected one of: bytes, unicode

Comment: I am currently on a mac fyi

Comment: Then try:
    file_path = file_path.encode("utf8")

Comment: AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: so maybe st.file_uploader() takes as argument just str. Then try delete line: file_path = Path(path) and use path as argument.

Comment: I don't know how Python works on mac, but you can try it.

Comment: streamlit.file_uploader(label, type=None, accept_multiple_files=False, key=None) these are the attributes

Comment: and what is the 'label' ? Why you trying to put path into this argument? What returns that func?

Comment: It's just a text that is shown above the upload bar.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as the answer. As @dsuzer mentions, the first argument is the label, not where the data is saved. See my later answer to see how you can actually save the result as a file.